# What are the things that I should save to a file/db with Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I wrote a small tic-tac-toe game. So far, the computer plays against itself using random moves.

Now, I want to apply reinforcement learning by writing an agent that will explore or exploit based on the knowledge it has on the current state of the board.

The part I don't understand is this:
What does the agent use to train itself for the current state? Lets say a RNG bot (o) player does this:

```
[..][..][..]

[..][x][o]

[..][..][..]
```

Now the agent has to decide what the best move should be. A well trained one would pick 1st, 3rd, 7th or 9th. Does it look up a similar state in the DB that led him to a win? Because if so, I think I will need to save every single move into the DB up to eventually it's end state (win/lose/draw state), and that would be quite a lot of data for a single play?

If I'm thinking this through wrong, I would like to know how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Learning**

1) Observe a current board state s;

2) Make a next move based on the distribution of all available V(s') of next moves. Strictly the choice is often based on Boltzman’s distribution of V(s'), but can be simplified to maximum-value move (greedy) or, with some probability epsilon, a random move as you are using;

3) Record s' in a sequence;

4) If the game finishes, it updates the values of the visited states in the sequence and starts over again; otherwise, go to 1).

**Game Playing**

1) Observe a current board state s;

2) Make a next move based on the distribution of all available V(s') of next moves;

3) Until the game is over and it starts over again; otherwise, go to 1).

Regarding your question, yes the look-up table in Game Playing phase is built up in the Learning phase. Every time the state is chosen from the all the V(s) with a maximum possible number of 3^9=19683. Here is [a sample code written by Python](https://github.com/tansey/rl-tictactoe/blob/master/tictactoe.py) that runs 10000 games in training.